# Python with xampp

Tags: python, apache

I want to create a .py file and display simple html code, just like I simply open any php file. I've put file.py inside of the c:/xampp/cgi-bin directory, I've enagled .py extension in apache configs, but...am I doing this the right way? What next?

How to open this file? localhost/cgi-bin/file.py displays the internal server 500 error with the note "Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need Choose a web framework. CherryPy. Pylons. Django.